# wordpress multisite get_the_post_thumbnail can't set size

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I have WordPress with multisite, so it will be pc and mobile version. On my pc version, I can use

`wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($id), array('210','210'))`

But on my mobile version, it doesn't work. I can get the image but the `size didn't change.`

Do anyone know why? 
Do I need to set something else?

Thank you

Comment: have you checked if you have some css overwriting the size? - have you checked that the correct template is being used? - have you seen if the size exists? have you tried to regenerate thumbnails on the mobile site? etc etc etc - We can't guess everything, so we need to know what you have tried, show us some code examples :)

Comment: Please see this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108341/wp-get-attachment-image-src-does-not-return-what-i-want

Comment: @Stender I already check that all, i'm afraid there is some problem with multisite type? I can show the image, but when i use array(210,210) or event thumbnail/large size, the size still didn't change at all..

Comment: @GufranHasan my problem is i can't change the size.. But it works fine on my pc version, only on the multisite (mobile) version it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Hi @beginnerprogrammer, I am currently on Multisite. I have created 12 different subdomains for native languages in India.

Comment: @GufranHasan Ah really? so, is there any problem with setting the size? i tried to use var_dump, and the array already show the new size, but when my image still show (natural size 600*400).. do you know why? Thanks! ^^

Comment: @beginnerprogrammer, nope, everything is working fine.

Comment: @GufranHasan So do you have any idea what is wrong with my multisite? I already tried everything but still nothing work

Comment: @GufranHasan i think i found the problem, how do you generate thumbnail on your multisite? When i upload image on my multisite, it doesn't make any thumbnail, like -250x140, etc, etc.. usually wordpress will make it when we upload right?

Comment: Exactly @beginnerprogrammer, it's here http://www.studiograsshopper.ch/web-development/wordpress-featured-images-add_image_size-resizing-and-cropping-demo/